# How to change permission of folder to not read/write in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, permissions, chmod

I need to change the permissions of an existing folder to be "without permission" - meaning they cannot be read/write.

Is there a way to do this in python (windows)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it using `os.chmod` but you can only set  stat.S_IWRITE in windows and stat.S_IREAD  https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

Comment: Is that mean I can't set permission of folder to no read/write?

Comment: you can change the folder permission you have to give the folder path

Answer (score 0):

use os.chmod().
os.chmod(path, stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IROTH)